# User profile sync service not start - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, ups

How can start user profile sync service with status **disabled** in SharePoint 2013 in PowerShell

- I am using the farm account
- the farm account in the local admin
- the FIM services are started

I checked all online articles with no luck, please help me with new suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** Make sure that you have restarted the timer service after adding the farm account to the local administrator group.

**Second,** In case, you have SharePoint 2013 SP1 with SQL Server 2014, you must patch your farm with a cumulative update in May 2014 or later to can start User Profile Sync Service.

**Third,** Make sure that the UPS service is not stuck on another server, it must run only on one server,

**Fourth,** Stop the UPS as mentioned at [Restart SharePoint Service Application using PowerShell](http://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/30/start-stop-sharepoint-service-applications-using-powershell)

**Fifth,** After Stopping the UPS, start it via CA, Make sure that you have opened the CA as administrator when starting the UPS again.

**Check** other causes for this boring issue at

- [User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on Starting](http://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/14/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting)
- [User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](http://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped)

Comment: Thank you, after installing the latest update it worked